# How do i write a sql query that is contingent on 2 columns in one conditional?

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

Take the following psuedo query on a table called userscore:

```
select average of userscore.points
where (userid = userid)
and ((userscore.year != given year) && (userscore.week != given week))
```

How do i write a query that will filter out a specific week/year column combination? For example this week is the 29th week of 2020. How do i write a query that will filter out only the 29th week of 2020 and not the 29th weeks of 2019/2018/2017 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i write a query that will filter out only the 29th week of 2020 and not the 29th weeks of 2019/2018/2017 etc?

This is more of a question about boolean logic than SQL.

Assuming that `given_year` and `given_week` are the parameters to your query, you want something like:

```
where not (year = given_year and week = given_week)
```

You can also express this with `or`:

```
where year <> given_year or week <> given_week
```